# MouseAdapter class and mouseMoved

Tags: java, events

If I register with `addMouseListener` a Component and then I pass it a new `MouseAdapter`
the motions event aren't generated because I must use `addMouseMotionListener`...

and conversely if I use `addMouseMotionListener` with `MouseAdapter` I can't use click events ecc.

so really I don't understand why `MouseAdapter` implements also `MouseMotionListener` and `MouseWheelListener`...

it creates only confusion!

Comment: What mouse events do you need to track? Adding a `MouseAdapter` with `addMouseListener` will allow you to track pretty much anything. Can you show your code for the MouseAdapter?

Comment: I wanted to track click and motion events together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in this way you can exactly do what you want: listen for both motion and click events in the same listener class:

```
MouseAdapter adapter = new MouseAdapter ({
    // Override here all the methods you need
});

widget.addMouseListener(adapter);    
widget.addMouseMotionListener(adapter);
```

This way your adapter will be notified of both Motion and clicks events.